# Changing webcam properties in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, logitech

I am trying to record video from my webcam(Logitech C920) of resolution 1280x720. I am using v4l2 to change the height and width. 
Using v4l2-ctl --all does reflect the change of height and width.
But when I try recording a video through OpenCV3 (python) it records with a resolution of 640x480.
According to certain solutions online I tried changing the cap_v4l.cpp file to change the default values of width and height. But that doesn't work.

Note: I want to get in working without using cap.set. I am using Ubuntu16, python3 and Opencv3.

Comment: Does your camera supports `1280x720` resolution ?

Comment: @ZdaR yes it does